# How do i load a viewcontroller from a xib file?

Tags: swift, delegates, xib

I tried to load a viewcontroller from a custom cell using delegates.But i get nil from the set delegate!
Here is a sample if anyone can help!
1. In Cell

```
protocol hotelFindDelegate{
func modalDidFinished(modalText: String)
}
class hotelFindCell: UITableViewCell {

var delegate:hotelFindDelegate?
@IBAction func findButton(sender: AnyObject) {       

    self.delegate!.modalDidFinished("HELLO")
    print("Damn nothing works")
}
```

2. In Main View

```
class MainViewController:hotelFindDelegate {
let modalView = hotelFindCell()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.modalView?.delegate = self  
}

func modalDidFinished(modalText: String){
 let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:          nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HotelListVC") as UIViewController

 self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
 self.modalView.delegate = self
 print(modalText)  
}
```

Comment: You want to load VC from XIB..? Your given code is not matching with your question.

Comment: Yes! I'm trying using delegates. Don't mind the code.

Comment: That's okay if you use delegates or do something else but your code should match to your requirements at least. First you decide you want to load view controller fom XIB or storyboard..?

Comment: Load viewcontroller from xib

Answer (score 4):

> To load view controller from XIB do the following steps.

```
let settingVC : SettingsViewController = SettingsViewController(nibName :"SettingsViewController",bundle : nil)
```

> later on you can push the same view controller object like

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("viewController", owner: self, options: nil)